# Issues assigning elements to vector of type function (functions as objects)

Tags: c++

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6y0bp-mnYU0) and in it its covering using functions as objects. I have the following code:

```
double multby2(double num) {
    return num * 2;
}

double multby3(double num) {
    return num * 3;
}

int main()
{

auto times2 = multby2; //store function as variable 
 cout << "5 * 2 = " << times2(5) << endl; //so here times2 becomes multby2. I guess an object of it?
 vector<function<double(double)>> funcs(2); //vector that takes type dbl func with element size of 2
        funcs[0] = multby2(10);
        funcs[1] = multby3;
        cout << "2 * 10 = " << funcs[0](10) << endl;
}
```

When I try to compile `funcs[0] = multby2(10);`, it gives me the error:

```
Error C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'double' (or there is no acceptable conversion
```

How come this is so? How come I can do `cout << "2 * 10 = " << funcs [0] (10) << endl;` but can't bypass this step by just assigning an argument to `multby(2)` and putting it into the vector like I tried to at `funcs[0] = multby2(10)`. You'll also notice I can do `cout << "5 * 2 = " << times2(5) << endl;` I thought I could follow the same idea and just insert the double to be multiplied inside the vector element assignment.

Comment: You can't do what you're trying because your `vector` stores `std::function<double(double)>`s, not `double`s.  They're completely different types.

Comment: Should be `funcs[0] = multby2;`

Comment: @StephenNewell it sores function<double(double)> which is literally the same thing I tried to feed it with multby2(10). multby2 is a double that takes a double. Look at it's definition. How is multby2 different by multby2(10)? its the same function, except the later has an argument

Comment: @skrrrt yes, but why can't I do funcs[0] = multby2(10). This is a function of type double that is supposed to take a double as its parameter

Comment: as @StephenNewell said  `multby2(10)` returns a `double` not a `function` type so you cannot store it in `vector` of `function`

Comment: *"multby2 is a double that takes a double"* -- no, `multby2` is a **function** that takes a `double` (and returns a `double`).

Comment: *"How is multby2 different by multby2(10)?"* -- `multby2` is a function (that takes a `double` and returns a double) while `multby2(10)` is the (`double`) value returned by said function when invoked with the argument `10`.

Comment: @skrrrt I am new to all this. So when we use the <function> keyword, that means return a type function not double, even though it says function<double(double)>. How would you describe vector<function<double(double) as a vector? vector that takes function type? Also how come trthen you can do funcs[0](10)? you are forcing the vector to return a double no?

Comment: I think this is the point where someone usually interjects that learning C++ from videos typically ends in failure, while [learning from a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) tends to fare better.

Comment: @JaMiT with what you are saying, that vector should be able to take a function that returns a double then such as func[0] = multby2(10). here mult2 is returning a double which is what the vector should be able to take. A vector that takes a function that takes a double and returns a double

Comment: @JaMiT how would you describe this function then? double Domath(function<double(double)> func, double num)
    return func(num);
}  Its supposed to return a doubkle but it returns a func. THis code compiles

Comment: @edo101 `auto times2 = multby2;` Replace `auto` with what the actual type must be for that line to compile, and you'll get a better insight into what it actually means.

Comment: @dxiv I am new to c++, I debug and it says times2 is of type double(*)(double). I have no idea what this means sadly atm.

Comment: @edo101 +1 for knowing and using the debugger. That said, my advice would be to go back and review the basics until it becomes crystal clear that `times2` is a pointer to a function that takes a `double` argument and returns a `double` value. Moving on to `function` arrays will come easier *after* that.

Comment: @dxiv so that is to say that when we have vector<function<double(double)>> funcs(2), what its saying is that funcs is a vector of type function pointer to a function that takes a double and returns a double? so whenever we invoke <function> inside a data type or pass it as an argument in another function, its actually calling a function pointer?

Comment: @edo101 No, an array of two function pointers to this type of function would be `double (*timesx[2])(double) = { multby2, multby3 };` for example. Your `funcs[2]` is a vector of two `function` objects, instead, which is similar in some ways but very different in others. This is part of the "*basics*" and too vast to cover here.

Comment: @dxiv so it is a vector of function objects. so funcs[0] = multby2; is saying assign the function object multby2 to funcs[0]? If that is the case, then what is cout << "2 * 10 = " << funcs[0](10) << endl; doing? Are you not modifying the value stored in funcs[0] by assigning a value to it to be multiplied? How is funcs[0](10) a legal operation?

Comment: @edo101 In that example, `return func(num);` does not return a function. It returns a `double`. This is the same misunderstanding as in your question. I would strongly advise you to not try to deal with something as complex as containers of function objects until you have a stronger grasp of the basics.

Comment: @edo101 `what is cout << "2 * 10 = " << funcs[0](10) << endl; doing` Same as:
`function<double(double)> func = funcs[0]; double result = func(10); cout << "2 * 10 = " << result << endl;`. Seriously, though, don't expect to learn (good) C++ by trial and error.

Comment: @dxiv . Anyways, to your example, I will copy this over and test it. Although I don't get what you are saying.  
function<double(double)> func = funcs[0]  to me seems like you are initialzing a vector to one element (empty)/containing 0.  
double result = func(10) to me says you are somehow taking the function object which has not been assigned into the vector and passing it a parameter. I don't know why this owuld work. For one, the vector is empty. Isn't func supposed to hold pointers to functions? Isn't that what func objects are?